# "git reset --hard" command and "git clean -f" not setting staging area like most recent commit

Tags: git, reset, revert

I cloned a repository, toyed around a bit and (oops) made a mess of my code.  Now I just want to revert to a clean clone of the repository code and start over.

I attempted to use the following from the terminal of the working directory:

```
git reset --hard      # deletes watched filed in local working directory and staged area
git clean -n          # shows what will be deleted without actually deleting anything (for the faint of heart)
git clean -f          # deletes unwatched files
```

However, when I run `git status`, it still shows the messy files.

Is there a recommended way to reset your machine to the latest check in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git clean -n` only does a "dry-run" of `git clean` to show you what it will delete, it doesn't actually delete anything. You can run the following sequence of commands to clean up your working copy and staging area/index:

```bash
git reset -- .    # Clear the index/staging area
git checkout -- . # Revert changes in your working copy
git clean -df     # Recursively delete untracked files.
```

If you want, you could even make these into a git alias:

```bash
# Make the alias
git config --global alias.undo \
"!git reset -- . ; git checkout -- . ; git clean -df; git status"

# Usage
git undo
```

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, I used `sudo git reset --hard` and after entering my password, it cleared out my local repository history to a known state!  Although, I didn't know about git aliases.  That's  great and I will be sure to use it!

Comment: actually it depends on your set up on the server on which you are working, but I get what you are saying.  There are ways to avoid having to enter passwords and utilize ssh connections with *.pem files.  However, the machines I work on require me to use sudo in their current state.  Most people will not need to use sudo.